# Aliasing interface property

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to alias e.g. the [HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) property, the same way I can alias methods like

```
EventTarget.prototype.on = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener
```

I tried:

```
 HTMLElement.prototype.w = HTMLElement.prototype.offsetWidth
```

but got:

> TypeError: 'offsetWidth' getter called on an object that does not
>   implement interface HTMLElement.

Comment: you can get [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and then add [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with name what you want

Comment: @MarkC. `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` is _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy Absolutely correct, I had misread something. Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`offsetWidth` is a property, and when you do

```
HTMLElement.prototype.offsetWidth
```

really calling `get` function, so when you try if on prototype - you get error.

So you can't assign property, instead you can [get descriptor for this property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) with all settings, and then [define property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with this descriptor, but with name that you wish.

```js
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, "offsetWidth");
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "w", descriptor);

var p = document.getElementById('p');

console.log('offsetwidth=%i, w=%i',p.offsetWidth,p.w);
```

```html
<p id='p'>123</p>
```

and then you can call new `w` property on existing HTMLElement.

**UPDATE** for your comment.

If you want add function to object and call it without `()` you should define property with *getter*.

For more info about properties with sample see in doc: [MDN : Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "x", {
  get: function() { return this.getBoundingClientRect().left }
});

var p = document.getElementById('p');

console.log('left=%i, x=%i',p.getBoundingClientRect().left,p.x);
```

```html
<p id='p'>123</p>
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Is there a way to get something that would resemble `HTMLElement.prototype.x = HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect().left` to work? So basically aliasing the property of a method...? Not sure if that makes sense! The closest I got was using `Element.prototype.x = function() { return this.getBoundingClientRect().left }` but maybe there's some magic to make it work without using parentheses?

Comment: @Nightfever, if you want `Element.prototype.x` instead `Element.prototype.x()` you should add not function field, but `property`. Try see doc for [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) - you just need define getter

Comment: @Nightfever, try see updated answer, i think now it should be more clear :-)